# Datatables - Why row() method can not get index value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

here is my code (and [ajax data](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html)) to insert index column to table. But I don't know why console log don't see the index value. I tried searching solution but couldn't find it. Someone please help me, thanks you so much.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.11.5/datatables.min.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var table = $('#example').DataTable({
                ajax: '../ajax/data/objects_salary.txt',
                columns: [
                    {
                        "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                            return meta.row + 1;
                        }
                    },
                    { data: 'name' },
                    { data: 'position' },
                    { data: 'office' },
                    { data: 'extn' },
                    { data: "start_date" },
                    { data: "salary" }
                ]
            });
            $('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
                var data = table.row(this).data();
                console.log(data);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container mt-4 bt-4">
        <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Index</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>Progress</th>
                    <th>Start date</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Console log output

```
{
    "name": "Tiger Nixon",
    "position": "System Architect",
    "salary": "320800",
    "start_date": "2011/04/25",
    "office": "Edinburgh",
    "extn": "5421"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the `meta.row` index is NOT part of the ajax data for the table. `table.data()` shows only the **data** (i.e., what you set in the `data` key of `columns[]` initialization option.)

Indeed, `meta.row` is just an index you're rendering via the `meta` object that - [according to the Docs](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) - is:

> An object that contains **additional information about the cell** being
> requested. This object contains the following properties (...etc)

try this:

```
$('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
    const data = dt.row(this).data();
    const index = dt.row(this).index() + 1;

    const rowData = {...data, index};
    console.log(rowData);
});
```

**P.S.** `var` is legacy Javascript, use `const / let` instead (unless you've really good reasons to use `var`)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest changing the `id` to something else, ex. `salary_id`. if that doesn't work can you also upload your `objects_salary.txt`

Comment: You can see or download `objects_salary.txt` in [datatables](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html) (tab Ajax)